# Can I install `libspotify` on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, hard-float

Is it possible to get [libspotify](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/) working on the official Raspbian image?  I installed it but couldn't figure out why my applications couldn't link to it:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libspotify.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Looking at ldd, I noticed that everything else has a "hard-float" flag.

```
libspotify.so.12 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libspotify.so.12
libsoup-2.4.so.1 (libc6,hard-float) => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsoup-2.4.so.1
```

As far as I know there's no way to build your own copy of libspotify... Is there a way to link to a library that is not compiled with hard-float support in Raspbian?

Comment: I notice `libspotify.so.12` is in a different folder.  Is that path listed in /etc/ld.so.conf?  I would expect a more specific error if it was hard-float related.  "No such file or directory" usually means what it suggests - the file is not where the system is looking for it.

Comment: Have you run `ldconfig` since installing it?

Comment: Yeah, I have.  I also put a symlink to it in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ to see if that made any difference.  That's why I assumed it must be a hard-float issue.

Answer (score 2):

Libspotify works with soft float Raspbian. If you want Spotify to compile a hard float version of their library, go give kudos to the idea in their community page: http://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-Ideas/armhf-Spotify-library-for-DIY-projects/idi-p/140972

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible. The entire application will have to be soft-float and you must build any library the application uses, including the C library. If these libraries are shared, this has implications for other applications too. So, you may choose to link said application statically - with the exception of `libspotify` itself.

If I were you, I would implement a statically-linked thin wrapper around `libspotify` with a client-server interface - a `libspotify` server if you will. That way, you can build the front end using hard float libraries - the GUI is much faster using hard float.

#### References

1. [ARM Linux FAQ](http://www.arm.linux.org.uk/mailinglists/faq.php#f4)

#### PS

```
error while loading shared libraries: libspotify.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This error is unlikely to be related to soft/hard incompatibility issues.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I can't think of any other reason this should be having troubles.  I tried symlinking a copy of the library into a folder where the same application is successfully including other libraries from.  It still says it's not found :/  It's showing `libspotify.so.12 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libspotify.so.12` so I think it has found the library... it just doesn't consider it a suitable library or something

Answer (score 1):

There is a soft-float version of Raspbian available on the RPi Foundation's [download page](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads). Might give that a whirl, see if it works.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer providing a link?

Answer (score 0):

It is, sadly, related to the ARMHF. Libspotify doesn't support this. Unless Spotify creates a HF supporting library, or the despotify library is mature enough to handle HF, there is no way for spotify to work on most Raspberry XBMC builds.

As far as I know, Raspbian, RaspBMC, XBian and OpenElec use hard float.

Answer (score 0):

Good news! It seems there is now a beta version of the spotify lib hard-float!
You can find it here (not tested!):
https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/