# How to run spotify on Raspberry Pi

Tags: audio, kodi

I have tried to install spotimc in XBian but it did'nt work.
How can I play spotify in XBMC?
/Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not yet possible. The first spotify clients for the Raspberry Pi are likely to be based on `libspotify`, but according to [Can I install `libspotify` on Raspbian?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1209/86) and [armhf Spotify library for DIY projects](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-Ideas/armhf-Spotify-library-for-DIY-projects/idi-p/140972), it has not yet built for hard-float.

Comment: In the first question your answer says 'It should be possible'. :)

Comment: @Jivings That should be "It should be technically possible, but no one in their right mind would do it."

Answer (score 6):

It is, libspotify, now avaliable as a beta from  https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/

You will need to install libasound2-dev and libreadline-dev to be able to compile it though.

Comment: To compile the samples that is. The library itself is precompiled

Answer (score 4):

Ben Delarre has [written a post](http://delarre.net/posts/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-media-center.html) on setting up Spotify on his Xbian XBMC@RaspberryPi distro. He tried two alternatives, one using the Spotimc XBMC add-on and another using Mopidy. Mopidy is more of a stand-alone spotify server and is controlled remotely, e.g. via a client on your Android phone.

Spotimc is controlled via XBMC and as such requires you to have your TV/monitor turned on---at least until a remote is developed that can control. From what I can tell it was first published on the RaspBMC forums, but seemed like it worked for Xbian as well.

Mopidy required some adjusting of the XBMC installation in order to resolve library conflicts after Mopidy installation. The adjustments were simple (adding a single line in the XBMC config/path), but this may still require you to do further maintenance in later updates.

From what I can tell, both solutions employs the libspotify library already mentioned by Peter. They are also both implemented in python, and it seems the Mopidy guys has even written python bindings for libspotify, available separately on github. This might be a good starting point for others, if Mopidy does not fit their particular use-case as-is.

Links:

- http://docs.mopidy.com/en/latest/installation/raspberrypi/ (installation instructions for mopidy)
- https://github.com/mopidy/  (Mopidy's github repo, including separate python bindings for libspotify)
- http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?pid=50586#pid50586 (Spotimc
  at the RaspBMC forum)
- http://superrepo.org/script.audio.spotimc/ (Spotimc script)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get music from Spotify to your Raspberry is with [Pi MusicBox](http://www.pimusicbox.com/). That is a ready-to-go distribution based on raspbian that incorpoporates a pre-configured

- http://mopidy.com/
- that comes along with a Spotify plugin (mopidy-spotify)
- and lets you browse/search Spotify using a web interface

You need a Spotify premium account for this setup.

Answer (score 1):

Spotify is not available for ARM architecture which basic for Raspberry. 
But you can run x86 apps on ARM using emulators.

[This is a link](http://eltechs.com/run-spotify-on-raspberry-pi/) on step-by-step instruction to run Spotify using ExaGear Desktop emulator.

Answer (score -3):

I suppose it depends on what you're trying to do. Does this URL help?

https://github.com/woutervanwijk/Pi-MusicBox

Comment: Please don't give *link answers.* It is bad style. Explain the link, don't give it. Then you can link.

Comment: sorry no. As stated I have Xbian's XBMC installed, would love an ap in that software that could connect to Spotify!